# "Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve" message when trying to connect to GitHub

Tags: windows, git, github, git-extensions, openssh-for-windows

I am trying to migrate my software development environment to a new machine.  My team uses GitHub as our code repository, and I access it via Git Extensions to do push, pull, etc.

On the new machine, I have copied the folders from the old machine containing all the code, including the .git folder (to save time not having to download everything again from the central repo).

I installed git, PuTTY, and Git Extensions on my new machine.  I attempted to setup Git Extensions to work with the other two, but I'm having problems:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I have Git Extensions setup to use OpenSSH.  I have pageant started - maybe this isn't really needed?

To try to run this down, I opened a command prompt to use git directly.  When I typed `git pull`, I received the same message:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I looked at [Troubleshooting SSH - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh).  This wasn't very helpful, because it listed things to check without saying what to do if something didn't check out.  In spite of this, with the help of [Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)...

- I found that OpenSSH was disabled for some reason, so I started it
- I found that my key files were unrecognized, so I generated new ones.
- I associated the new keys with GitHub, following their directions

After all this, I still got the same error..

When I type the command `ssh -vT git@github.com`, I get this response:

> OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
> debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
> debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.4] port 22.
> debug1: Connection established.
> debug1: identity file ...
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-d815c248
> debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-d815c248
> debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
> debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\Users\******/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory

I don't know whether to focus on the $SSH_SK_PROVIDER problem or the known_hosts2 problem.  In either case, I don't know what to do next.  I don't have an environment variable named SSH_SK_PROVIDER, and I don't have a file named known_hosts2 - it's just known_hosts.  (I don't know why it's looking for known_hosts2.)

Can anyone help me sort this out???

Answer (score -3):

As it turned out, I overlooked a step described in [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).  I had to get a copy of the public key & add it to my GitHub account.  Now it works.

Comment: Wrong URL. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Fix the url please